# Ktor not serving static images properly

Tags: kotlin, static-files, ktor

I have a ktor server, and I'm trying to serve some static assets that are stored in resources folder `assets`.

```
static("/assets") {
    resources("assets")
}
```

For `.css` files it works when I fetch them with something like http://0.0.0.0:7200/assets/css/main.css, but when I try to fetch images with http://localhost:7200/assets/img/flags/uk.png, it returns a broken image, although it exists.

[image]

[image]

I've tried different image formats and paths. Also tried different ways of serving the resources, but none worked.

Edit (Beginning of image downloaded from browser):
[image]

Edit (Beginning of original file, why are they slightly different?):
[image]

Comment: What does it mean that the image is broken? Internet browser says it is malformed? Did you try to save it to disk and look inside to see what it is exactly?

Comment: Yep, tried downloading it, and it's somehow corrupted or malformed. So neither the browser nor the OS will display it properly.

Comment: When downloading the files, they seem to have some PNG metadata at the beginning of the file (see the image I just attached)

Comment: Comparing the original file with the one downloaded from the browser, there are slightly differences, but I'm not sure why. Encoding issue?

Comment: So it seems it replaced all non-ASCII bytes. Do you have a hex editor to see what exactly are these 3 bytes? It looks like they are always the same 3 bytes, so I won't be surprised if this is just a question mark or something like that in unicode. But I have no idea why is that.

Comment: I replaced the images with the hex viewer ones.

Comment: So it seems I was right, it is this char: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm encoded in UTF-8. But I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Could you please share an example image? What version of Ktor do you use? Is it reproducible with images in a local file system? Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it with random images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. It had nothing to do with Ktor, but with Gradle. Let me explain.
I have this configuration in my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.processResources {
    from(sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs)
    into("$buildDir/resources/main")
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE

        filter(
            ReplaceTokens::class, "tokens" to mapOf(
                "BUILD_VERSION" to version,
                "BUILD_DATE" to DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(ZonedDateTime.now()),
                "BUILD_MACHINE" to InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostName
            )
        )
}
```

And for some reason, it was messing around the images. Solution, apply the processing only to the files I want, in this case, only `application.conf`. So I now have it like this, and it doesn't corrupt image files from resources:

```
tasks.processResources {
    from(sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs)
    into("$buildDir/resources/main")
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE

    filesMatching("application.conf") {
        filter(
            ReplaceTokens::class, "tokens" to mapOf(
                "BUILD_VERSION" to version,
                "BUILD_DATE" to DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(ZonedDateTime.now()),
                "BUILD_MACHINE" to InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostName
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your willingness to help.